# Complex wordpress query with conditional custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show a calendar in my sidebar. Posts that should show up in this calendar have a custom field called **event_date**. The field is populated with a date, formatted like YYYYMMDD. I try to make just **events in the future** show up.

My first plan, to only show posts with the event_date field, is succeeded:

```
<?php
$args = array
  (
  'showposts' => 10,
  'meta_key' => 'event_date',
  'meta_value' => '',
  'meta_compare' => '!='
  );
query_posts( '$args' );
?>
```

But I have no idea how to proceed from here and only filter out the events in the future. Ofcourse I can filter later in the while loop, but that doesn't sound like a clean solution.

If it's possible to sort them by date that would be even more amazing, but otherwise I'll just trow everything in an array and calculate the order from there.

Using a timestamp instead of yyyymmdd is not a solution, as that will require a lot of education to the editors.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing out your question always helps. I got it! Thanks for reading anyways!

Here is my solution, stupid that I didn't figure this out before:

```
<?php
$args = array
(
'showposts' => 10,
'meta_key' => 'event_date',
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_value' => date("Ymd", date("U")-3600*24),
'meta_compare' => '>'
);
query_posts( $args );
?>
```

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out :) - You should post your solution as an answer so that others can benefit! On stackoverflow you are allowed to accept your own answer as the correct one.